# Java Project created in Eclipse on Windows.How to run this in Ubuntu-Server?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-server, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I wrote some programs for Oracle Service Instances using the SDK in Eclipse.I also included some Referenced Libraries in Eclipse Project.
Now I want to run those programs from that Eclipse Java Project on to differnt OS(Ubuntu-Server).
How can I do that? Help me doing this!

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be about how to run java code on Ubuntu, and is not specific to any Oracle SDKs.

In general, you should package the application as a jar in Eclipse, then move that jar to the Ubuntu server. Then run that jar from the command line on the Ubuntu server. For more info see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal).